# Setting Spring Profile variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have two Spring profiles: `dev` and `test`. I want to set the active profile in the server environment, I don't want to set it in my code so that wherever I deploy my application the profile gets loaded based on the profile in the server.
 How can I do that?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can simply set a system property on the server as follows...

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

**Edit:** To add this to tomcat in eclipse, select `Run -> Run Configurations` and choose your Tomcat run configuration.  Click the `Arguments` tab and add `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` at the end of `VM arguments`.  Another way would be to add the property to your catalina.properties in your `Servers` project, but if you add it there omit the `-D`.

**Edit:** For use with **Spring Boot**, you have an additional choice.  You can pass the property as a program argument if you prepend the property with two dashes.

Here are two examples using a Spring Boot executable jar file...

**System Property**

```bash
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test myproject.jar
```

**Program Argument**

```bash
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.profiles.active=test
```

Comment: I am new to Spring profiles ."ON THE SERVER". Where and how exactly do I need to set it.

Comment: One more thing is that, I am starting tomcat through eclipse and not through commmand line.

Comment: What server are you using?  If you are using tomcat, you can add this to the $CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties but omit the -D so you would just add spring.profiles.active=test

Comment: `--spring.profiles.active=test` is a Spring Boot paradigm which did not exist in 2013 when I wrote this answer.  If you choose to use it, it must be used as a program argument, which comes after the class or jar name.  The `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` approach, which uses system properties, still works, but it must come before the class or jar name.  I'll try to update this answer to better reflect the current spring approaches.

Comment: Is there any way to have different settings for each webapp / context? If I deploy Spring Boot app1 and want it to run with profile x and Spring Boot app2 with profile y, setting a environment var or JVM system property won't work. Is there any way to initialize the profile from a context environment?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, you should be using an embedded tomcat, so you would be free to use different program arguments, system properties or even environment variables since each app would be running in a separate jvm.

Comment: neat, `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` works as jvm argument, not `-DSPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev`. (useful while deploying using amazon elastic beanstalk)

Comment: But with this, when you run this on the server, you have to use nohup right? Or this also works when running  the executable jar as a service?

Comment: can  i change profile name while system running (profile for different data sources )

Answer (score 33):

There are at least two ways to do that:

1. defining context param in web.xml – that breaks "one package for all environments" statement. I don't recommend that
2. defining system property `-Dspring.profiles.active=your-active-profile`

I believe that defining system property is a much better approach. So how to define system property for Tomcat? On the internet I could find a lot of advice like "modify catalina.sh" because you will not find any configuration file for doing stuff like that. Modifying catalina.sh is a dirty unmaintainable solution. There is a better way to do that.

Just create file setenv.sh in Tomcat's bin directory with content:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```

and it will be loaded automatically during running catalina.sh start or run.

[Here is a blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160406155933/http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/03/27/spring-3-1-profiles-and-tomcat-configuration/) describing the above solution.

Comment: For windows use set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.profiles.active=dev (no quotes)

Comment: I think, it's better to use CATALINA_OPTS see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat

Comment: Above link is dead.

Answer (score 11):

For Eclipse, setting **`-Dspring.profiles.active`** variable in the VM arguments should do the trick.

Go to

> Right Click Project --> Run as --> Run Configurations --> Arguments

And add your **`-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`** in the ***VM arguments***

Answer (score 5):

In the `<tomcat-home>\conf\catalina.properties` file, add this new line:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Answer (score 4):

as System environment Variable:

**Windows:**
Start -> type "envi" select environment variables and add a new:

`Name: spring_profiles_active
Value: dev` (or whatever yours is)

**Linux:**
add following line to /etc/environment under PATH:

`spring_profiles_active=prod` (or whatever profile is)

then also `export spring_profiles_active=prod` so you have it in the runtime now.

Comment: This works great (tested in windows), also when running your application in an OSGI container. Just remember to restart the JVA instance after setting it, and make sure that the System Property named "spring.profiles.active" is unset. FYI, this does not actually set the System Property, but the Spring Environment instance profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For Tomcat 8:

Linux :

Create setenv.sh and update it with following:

export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev

Windows:

Create setenv.bat and update it with following:

set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev