# spring profile activation (non-programmatically)

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to activate a spring profile non-programmatically and is it possible to decide which profile is used at runtime?

Comment: Check this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814497/setting-spring-profile-variable

Answer (score 2):

You can `@Autowire` `Environment` class which has methods to check active profiles at runtime. Here is [environment class documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html).

As for non-programatic profile activation you can start your app like this:

```
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So `spring.profiles.active` is there to set profile.

Comment: is it possible to set the spring.profiles.active property using Ant build file?

Comment: Maven can so I suppose that ant can as well but haven't used it in ages. In maven you can add `<jvmArguments>-Dspring.profiles.active=devel</jvmArguments>` to maven execution plugin