# How to specify a profile when deploying a Spring boot war file to Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

At the moment, all my properties are defined in the file `src/main/resources/application.properties`. However, I would like to have properties files relating to different profiles in the `src/main/resources/config` folder, and I want to be able to choose any of them. such as:

- `application-DEV.properties`
- `application-TEST.properties`
- `application-SERVER1.properties`

So, the question is how to select these properties. If I was compiling to a `jar` file, I could do that easily by specifiying the profile when running the `jar` file, but here I just copy the generated `war` file to a Tomcat webapps directory.

Comment: You mean you have all those profile specific properties available int the packaged war and want to get the war started with a specific one? Or you want to have a profile specific property in the in the webapps directory?

Comment: Say, I have all of them present in the src/main/resources/config folder, and I want to choose one of them.

Comment: JAVA_OPTS in Tomcat Config?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814497/setting-spring-profile-variable. The option can be set as JAVA_OPTS like @Learner already said.

Comment: I prefer to do it by modifying the catalina.properties file. Problem with JAVA_OPTS is that you have to do it differently on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I've found a way to do that. In the `conf` directory of Tomcat, add this line to the file `catalina.properties` there.

```
spring.profiles.active=<YOUR_PROFILE>
```

Replace `<YOUR_PROFILE>` here of course with your profile's name. For example if you are using `application-TEST.properties`, it would be the following.

```
spring.profiles.active=TEST
```

Comment: How do you customize for multiple war files? say `app1.war` should activate `prod.properties` where as `app2.war` should activate `production.properties`??

Comment: It could also be done this way: set env in `/opt/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` using `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=test"`. `catalina.sh`, which is the main startup script, looks for `setenv.sh` for additional java options

Answer (score 0):

You can define Jvm Argument `-Dspring.profiles.active=<PROFILE>` on server start up file (.bat/.sh) depending on your environment.