# JVM Command Line Option

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to change the garbage collector on the server's JVM to combat a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` exception, as per some of the other questions I've found on here. Although I've ran into some confusion about the usage of these command line options. This is what I'm doing:

```
java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

However I'm getting the `usage` message, and no indication it has changed at all.

This is the output I'm seeing:

> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>              (to execute a class)
>      or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file)
>   where options include: ........

Is this the correct use of the command line arguments? Am I making a stupid mistake? (it happens a lot)

Answer (score 2):

Command line flags like that one are used by the JVM you create when running the `java` command, **they're not "global" switches**.

To use the flag, include it in the VM arguments of your normal execution.

Also, note that enabling [`ConcMarkSweepGC`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) will not really help you, since all that it enables it potentially more proactive garbage collection. You either have:

- a memory leak in your app (usually dangling references, [but not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java)).
- your webapp simply requires more memory to run, in which case you need to [use `-Xmx` to increase the max heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for).

Comment: Yeah dude, sorry but that means absolutely nothing to me. I've attached the argument into my start up script on the tomcat server. The problem is, I don't know *where* or *how* to use these commands. Could you explain a little more specifically?

Comment: @chris : I can, now that you've actually specified you're using Tomcat. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat) describes how to use VM options in this case. That's where. As to **how**, that's a very large topic. I'll edit my answer to include some pointers.