# Best way to increase heap size in catalina.sh file for XWiki?

Tags: tomcat, catalina, xwiki

I am trying to configure XWiki on Ubuntu 14.0.4 for an project. I keep getting an error that says: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. I have tried Google'ing for a solution, but nothing that I have found has worked. The majority of solutions say to allocate more memory to the JVM in the catalina.sh file, by using a line such as "CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx800m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m". How do I implement this change/where do I put it in the catalina.sh file? Thanks for the help.

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

How did you installed Tomcat exactly ? If it was trough apt-get you have a few information on http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/InstallationViaAPT#HTomcatUsability. The standard Tomcat Debian package is supposed to be configured using /etc/default/tomcat7 (change the version depending on your Tomcat version).