# Tomcat for Windows Automated setup

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, tomcat

Tomcat for Windows setup question..

**Answer is below..**

Looking at Tomcat zip file - Not the executable setup installer.

after running:

> service install tomcat

tomcatNw.exe shows in the Java tab:

```
-Dcatalina.home=D:\tomcat
-Dcatalina.base=D:\tomcat
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\tomcat\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\tomcat\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\tomcat\conf\logging.properties
```

what I would like to see is if the batch file could add in at the bottom of this:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxNewSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+AggressiveHeap
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=D:\tomcatdumps_1\hprof-dumps\heapdump.hprof
-verbose:gc
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

We see in the service.bat file the following:

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" --JvmMs 128 --JvmMx 256
```

I think all would need to do is to remove:  --JvmMs 128 --JvmMx 256

We see in the catalina.bat file the following:

```
%EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%

%EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
```

And I think it should be a matter of adding to the catalina.bat file.

**Answer:**
Rather than making changes to the batch file, I think I can do the changes this way:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Java" /v Options /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "-Dcatalina.home=D:\tomcat"\0"-Dcatalina.base=D:\tomcat"\0"-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\tomcat\endorsed"\0"-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\tomcat\temp"\0"-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"\0"-Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\tomcat\conf\logging.properties"\0"-Xms1024m"\0"-Xmx1024m"\0"-XX:MaxNewSize=512m"\0"-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"\0"-XX:+AggressiveHeap"\0"-XX:+PrintGCDetails"\0"-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"\0"-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"\0"-XX:HeapDumpPath=D:\tomcatdumps_1\hprof-dumps\heapdump.hprof"\0"-verbose:gc"\0"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086"\0"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"\0"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Java" /v JvmMs /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Java" /v JvmMx /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

We will need to change to Tomcat7 or Tomcat8 as necessary.

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you add that to the `.bat` file?

Comment: This should be your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat