# how to set java -Djava.library.path="\home\path.SomeFile.so" in linux environment for Tomcat instance?

Tags: java, linux, environment, tomcat8

How do i set it in the Linux environment?

I keep getting the below error.
I am assuming its because i have to set the `-Djava path .` in eclipse i set in the arguments in the run configuration.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/temp/librocksdbjni1678787310187961141..so: libgflags.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLi
```

Comment: You don 't. Linux paths don't contain backslashes, and `java.library.path` doesn't contain .so files. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Docker contains \ path, and we need to add to CATALINA_OPTS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the JVM parameter in [path to tomcat]/bin/catalina.sh, in the variable CATALINA_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS.

The value should be a valid Linux path (or paths) containing your libraries.

You can refer to this question:
[add jvm options in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat)

Comment: You should NEVER edit catalina.sh or catalina.bat. You should add a setenv.bat or setenv.sh file. Look here and search for "(3.4)". https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/RUNNING.txt