# Can not past Java VM arguments to my TOMCAT web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I need to communicate Java and Matlab to make a certain job and deploy my code as a webservice.
I am working with Ubuntu 16.04, Eclipse Neon, Tomcat 8.5, Axis 2 and Finally Matlab 2017a.

I have the Full code working  as Java Aplication. And as you can Imagine  I need to add a `.jar` file to the project (its name is "engine.jar") but also I need to add a **PATH AS VM ARGUMENT**  (  In run configuration, I select my project and write : `-Djava.library.path="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64"` as VM Argument )  without the last my code does not work.

Now I am trying to  deploy my web service,  to do that in a dynamic web project  I wrote all  the code and try to call it from a Web client, but an error shows up when I run the client ( This error also appears  if I delete  the VM argument on my Java project).

I have tried a lot of stuff  to fix this.

I created a sentv.sh file on `/Tomcatroot/bin` with this line:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64"
```

I also have this line on my .barsch file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64
```

But nothing has worked yet

thanks in advance.

Comment: "error shows up when I run the client" - If you're going to mention you get an error, please at least share the error with us so we can better understand what the problem is and try to help. thanks.

Comment: @downshift 
Failed to load Nativemvm library: no nativemvm in java.library.path

Thanks to you !

Comment: Pretty sure you want `set CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/lib"`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - maybe.  But it depends on where it is being set.  If the web container is launched in the normal way as a system service, then putting stuhh into the user's ".bashrc" or into the current shell environment variables will have no effect.

Comment: set CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/‌​lib" this path does not exist.  What should I do ?

Comment: If not in bashrc , where should I Set it ? Or how should I launch the server ?

Comment: @NicoleArévalo, maybe try setting in `catalina.sh` https://stackoverflow.com/a/39929967/1248974