# How can I edit Tomcat options using Powershell?

Tags: java, powershell, tomcat, jvm, java-opts

I'm developping a (humble) script to edit Tomcat options in powershell.
It's installed as a service and I'm running this as an administrator (for now).

I think the problem is when I execute the Set-ItemProperty with several options.

After that, the service never starts.
It does, when I go manualy to Tomcat /bin directory, starts tomcat6w, and cut/paste manually my options in Java tab. Then I click ok, and the service answers.

Would you have an idea of what I'm missing ? Frustrating stuff, because my script looks almost ok.

PS: you don't need to understand the french here, but ask if needed.

```
#Script de configuration des options Tomcat :

Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

#Variables :
#nom du serveur : 
$servername=hostname

#$memoirelibre=(Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_OperatingSystem").freephysicalmemory*1024/1MB
$pathtomcat = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\*"
$pathtomcatjava = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Java"
$pathtomcatstart = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Start"
$pathtomcatstop = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Stop"
$optionsTomcatJava = Get-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatjava -Name "Options" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Options" -ErrorAction Stop
$runningtomcat = Get-Service | Where { $_.Status -eq "Running"} | findstr Tomcat6
$lecteur = "D:"
#$urlsetaclexe = ""
[string] $oui = "oui"
[string] $non = "non" 

#Variables pour les options Tomcat par défaut : 
$XmsValue=384
$XmxValue=1024
$MaxMetaspaceSizeValue=384
$XssValue=256
$esbport=1100

#Renommage du service :
Set-Service Tomcat6 -DisplayName "mycompany-Tomcat"
    #echo "Le service Tomcat6 est renommé en mycompany-Tomcat."

#Gestion des paramètres du service : 
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatstart -Name "Class" -Value "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatstart -Name "WorkingPath" -Value "$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatstart -Name "Arguments" -Value "start"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatstart -Name "Mode" -Value "jvm"

Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatstop -Name "Class" -Value "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatstop -Name "WorkingPath" -Value "$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatstop -Name "Arguments" -Value "stop"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatstop -Name "Mode" -Value "jvm"

Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatjava -Name "Java Virtual Machine" -Value "$lecteur\mycompany\Java\jdk-8u45-windows-x64-security\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatjava -Name "Java Classpath" -Value "$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
    #echo "Le service mycompany-Tomcat est configuré."

#Récupération des options JAVA existantes / modifications
#Si les options sont vides 
#    alors : je les rajoute toutes en posant des questions
#Sinon je demande de nouvelles valeurs


if ( $optionsTomcatJava -eq {} ) 
{
#Questions pour les options : 

[int] $XmsValue = Read-Host "Quelle valeur pour l'option Xms (réponse en chiffres) ? Exemple : 384"

[int] $XmxValue = Read-Host "Quelle valeur pour l'option Xmx (réponse en chiffres) ? Exemple 1024" 

[int] $MaxMetaspaceSizeValue = Read-Host "Quelle valeur pour l'option MaxMetaspace (réponse en chiffres) ? Exemple : 384" 

[int] $XssValue = Read-Host "Quelle valeur pour l'option Xss (réponse en chiffres) ? Exemple : 256" 

[int] $esbport = Read-Host "Quel numéro de port pour RMIFop ? (base 1100)"

Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatjava -Name "Options" -Value "-Dcatalina.home=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat `
-Dcatalina.base=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat`
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat\endorsed`
-Djava.io.tmpdir=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat\temp`
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager`
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat\conf\logging.properties`
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.disabled=False`
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.rmiConnector.registryPort=$esbport`
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.createRmiConnector=True`
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.mbeanObjectDomainName=mycompany.esb.camel`
-Dsun.rmi.activation.execTimeout=1800000`
-Xms$XmsValue`m`
-Xmx$XmxValue`m`
-Djava.awt.headless=true`
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=$MaxMetaspaceSizeValue`m`
-Xss$XssValue`k`
-Dsolr.solr.home=$lecteur\mycompany\solr`
-Dmycompany.licence.dir=$lecteur\mycompany\licences" -Force
}

#}

else {
    $questionXms = Read-Host -prompt "L'option Xmsvalue est à $XmsValue, faut il la modifier [o/n] ?" 
        if ( $questionXms -eq "o" ) 
            {
            [int] $XmsValue = Read-Host -prompt "Quelle valeur pour l'option Xms (réponse en chiffres) ? Exemple : 384"
            }

    $questionXmx = Read-Host -prompt "L'option Xmxvalue est à $XmxValue, faut il la modifier [o/n] ?" 
        if (  [string] $questionXmx -eq "o" ) 
            {
            [int] $XmxValue = Read-Host -prompt "Quelle valeur pour l'option Xmx (réponse en chiffres) ? Exemple 1024" 
            }

    $questionMaxmeta = Read-Host -prompt "L'option MaxMetaspaceSizeValue est à $MaxMetaspaceSizeValue, faut il la modifier [o/n] ?" 
        if (  [string] $questionMaxmeta -eq "o" ) 
            {
            [int] $MaxMetaspaceSizeValue = Read-Host -prompt  "Quelle valeur pour l'option MaxMetaspace (réponse en chiffres) ? Exemple : 384" 
            }

    $questionXss = Read-Host -prompt "L'option Xssvalue est à $XssValue, faut il la modifier [o/n] ?" 
        if (  [string] $questionXss -eq "o" ) 
            {
            [int] $XssValue = Read-Host -prompt  "Quelle valeur pour l'option Xss (réponse en chiffres) ? Exemple : 256" 
            }

    $questionesbport = Read-Host -prompt "L'option de port RMIFop est à $esbport, faut il la modifier [o/n] ?" 
        if (  [string] $questionesbport -eq "o" ) 
            {
            [int] $esbport = Read-Host -prompt  "Quel numéro de port ESB ? (base 1100)"
            }

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatjava -Name "Options" -Value "-Dcatalina.home=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat `
-Dcatalina.base=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat`
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat\endorsed`
-Djava.io.tmpdir=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat\temp`
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager`
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$lecteur\mycompany\Tomcat\conf\logging.properties`
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.disabled=False`
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.rmiConnector.registryPort=$esbport`
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.createRmiConnector=True`
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.mbeanObjectDomainName=mycompany.esb.camel`
-Dsun.rmi.activation.execTimeout=1800000`
-Xms$XmsValue`m`
-Xmx$XmxValue`m`
-Djava.awt.headless=true`
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=$MaxMetaspaceSizeValue`m`
-Xss$XssValue`k`
-Dsolr.solr.home=$lecteur\mycompany\solr`
-Dmycompany.licence.dir=$lecteur\mycompany\licences" -Force

       }





#(Re)démarrage du service :
#Si le service Tomcat n'est pas en running, je le redémarre.



    if ($runningtomcat -eq $false)
            {
            Write-Host "Le service mycompany-Tomcat n'est pas démarré. On le démarre."
            get-service Tomcat6 | Start-Service -Verbose
            }

    else    { 
            Write-Host "Le service mycompany-Tomcat n'est pas encore redémarré. On le redémarre."
            get-service Tomcat6 | restart-Service -Verbose

            }
```

Here is the error, I'm getting :

```
**Restart-Service : Impossible de démarrer le service « mycompany-Tomcat (Tomcat6) ».
Au caractère C:\Users\mycompany\Documents\scripteditiontomcat.ps1:159 : 35
+             get-service Tomcat6 | Restart-Service -Verbose
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service], ServiceCom 
   mandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand**
```

Another lead could be the direct edition of Tomcat configuration files. I just need to locate where my options variables are located ....

Comment: Probably not your issue but this seems like an odd choice: `$runningtomcat = Get-Service | Where { $_.Status -eq "Running"} | findstr Tomcat6` why not `$runningtomcat = Get-Service Tomcat6 | Where { $_.Status -eq "Running"}`

Comment: Indeed, not the issue, but you have a point.

Comment: Is the `*` at the end of the `$pathtomcat` supposed to be there?

Comment: Not really, but this variable is not called anyway, I deleted it.

Comment: Alright, there's been a development. I figured out that I'm not injecting a proper text value in Java Options (or jvm options). When I erased my escape characters, it started to work again. It is still un perfect because I'd like to encapsulate this somehow and I am still working on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I solved it by injecting values to a text file and get them back with a get-content.

```
$tomcatproperties = Get-Content -Path "d:\mycompany\install\scripts\tomcat-properties.txt"

echo $jvmopts >> "d:\artis\install\scripts\tomcat-properties.txt"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pathtomcatjava -Name "Options" -Value $tomcatproperties
```

Et voilà !

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat