# Apache Tomcat 9 fails on JDK 9

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am using Tomcat 9 on JDK 9 and started tomcat like -

C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.4\bin>catalina.bat start

On the consolde it is giving errors like -

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
```

When I search google it is mentioned to use 
    --add-modules java.xml.bind

But not sure about where to set this.  Please help.

Thanks,
-Anand

Comment: You probably want to include links to the web pages you researched already.

Comment: Does solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat

Comment: Hi, I am running Apache Tomcat as part of installation of APEX or ORDS.  So, I have no knowledge about Java or Apache Tomcat.  Not sure how to proceed because of issue with JDK 9 with Tomcat 9.  Can someone help me what exactly I need to do to get this running.  I am not able to understand how this link is suitable in my case  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j